# Export all but certain excel sheets to CSV via VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Based on some other stuff I found here, I have made the following script to do almost exactly what I want.  It will export all but 4 specific sheets in an excel file to CSV files, append dates to them, and save them to dated folders.  The only problem is it renames the sheets it exported in the original processing file.  How can I rectify this?

```
Sub SaveLCPWorksheetsAsCsv()

Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SaveToDirectory As String

Dim CurrentWorkbook As String
Dim CurrentFormat As Long

CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
' Store current details for the workbook

  SaveToDirectory = "C:\test\" & Format(Date - 1, "YYYYMM") & "\"

  If Len(Dir(SaveToDirectory, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir SaveToDirectory
  End If

  For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If WS.Name <> "Input" And WS.Name <> "Ref" And WS.Name <> "Total" And WS.Name <> "Affected Accounts" Then
        WS.SaveAs SaveToDirectory & WS.Name & "_" & Format(Date - 1, "YYYYMMDD"), xlCSV
    End If
  Next

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CurrentWorkbook, FileFormat:=CurrentFormat
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
' Temporarily turn alerts off to prevent the user being prompted
'  about overwriting the original file.

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Tester()

Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Copy 'creates a new workbook
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .SaveAs "C:\temp\" & ws.Name & "_blah.csv", xlCSV
            .Close False
        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```